# Newly created test case class is not shown under Test Navigator in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode7, xctest

My XCode version is 7.3.1 .

My project already has test project, and there are already some test case classes. I can see them when select the "Test Navigator" tab [image] which is one of this [image] on left top of XCode.

Now, I want to create a new test case, so I selected the new **Unit Test Case Class**:
[image]

And I add very simple code into it:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface MyTest : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation MyTest

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testExample {
    NSString* expected = @"my-test-string";
    XCTAssertEqual(expected, @"my-test-string");
}

@end
```

I need to run it, so I go to "Test Navigator" [image] again, but I can't see this test case class I just created. Why?

Comment: Check if the test is added to the test target.

Comment: Yes, it is in the test target.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Xcode is the only thing that worked for me in Xcode 9.0 beta 6.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Xcode adds the individual testmethods/classes only after the whole unit test target has been run at least once.

So select your test target, run all tests using Command u. After that you should see all tests in the test navigator and you can run them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the unit test appears in Test Navigator after you Save (CTRL+S) the unit test's file in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to keep the `test` prefix on the test methods, otherwise they are not recognized by the test framework, e.g.:

`func test_When_empty_Then_returnsNil() {`

**not**

`func when_empty_Then_returnsNil() {`